# Determine content of Windows-clipboard in LotusScript

Tags: windows, clipboard, lotus-notes, lotusscript, hcl-notes

Is there a way to determine what kind of data currently is in the clipboard?
I'm trying to check this on HCL Notes' QueryPaste-event, which occurs when a user is about to paste "something" into a view. It would be awesome if I could check whether the clipboard's content is a file - if so, I'd like to write this file to disc an process its content.

Any ideas about this?

Thanks,
Buzzy

Comment: A file is not a [standard clipboard format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats). Files live in the clipboard in the shape of shell objects. You'll need COM to get to the internals.

Comment: I am not even sure, if QueryPaste reacts to a paste that does NOT contain Notesdocuments... If you want to get the documents that have been copied, then you can look at ~clipbrd.ncf: It is a Notes Database that contains the copied Notes Documents and can be inspected with default LotusScript commands...

Comment: As Torsten said, QueryPaste in a view probably doesn't respond to pasting anything which isn't NotesDocuments. Also if someone copies NotesDocuments, they don't go into the Windows clipboard, but instead go into the local ~clipbrd.ncf database. My answer to another SO question provides some relevant code if you want to check documents in QueryPaste: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147353/retrieving-notesdocumentcollection-during-querypaste

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible for LotusScript to call Windows platform APIs to query the Windows clipboard, but doing what you want from a view's QueryPaste event isn't possible.

I've done some testing, and found that if a user hasn't copied any Notes documents in the current session (i.e. between starting Notes and quitting Notes), then a view's QueryPaste event doesn't run when trying to paste anything. QueryPaste **only** runs when pasting Notes documents.

Comment: Ok, I see - I didn't seriously expect it to work.
Thanks anyway :-)